# How to retry failed test specs in protractor jasmine

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to use protractor-retry mechanism to run my protractor e2e tests.
I have installed Protractor-retry package and added required things in conf.js file as below:

```
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var properties = PropertiesReader('config.properties');
var retry = require('protractor-retry').retry;
exports.config = {

plugins: [{
    package: 'jasmine2-protractor-utils',
    disableHTMLReport: false,
    disableScreenshot: false,
    //screenshotPath: './reports/screenshots',
    screenshotPath: './ExecutionResults/reports/screenshots',
    screenshotOnExpectFailure: true,
    screenshotOnSpecFailure: true,
    clearFoldersBeforeTest: true,
    htmlReportDir: './reports/htmlReports',
    failTestOnErrorLog: {
        failTestOnErrorLogLevel: 1100,
        excludeKeywords: ['keyword1', 'keyword2']
    }
}],
directConnect: true,
// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': properties.get('browserName'),
    }],

    onCleanUp: function(results) {
        retry.onCleanUp(results);
    },
suites: {
        test: '../test_spec/smoke/cards/test.js'
},

// Options to be passed to Jasmine.
allScriptsTimeout: properties.get('allscriptTimeOutSeconds'),
getPageTimeout: properties.get('pageTimeOut'),
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 2000000
},
onPrepare: function () {
    retry.onPrepare();
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    var width = 1400;
    var height = 1000;
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    browser.driver.get(properties.get('envUrl'),);
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);

    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        allureReport: {
            resultsDir: 'allure-results'
        }
    }));

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: 'testresults',
        filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
    }));
    var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        // setup the output path for the junit reports
        savePath: 'output/',
        consolidateAll: false
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    return global.browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) { });
},
afterLaunch: function() {
    return retry.afterLaunch(2);
 },

onComplete: function () {
    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        browserVersion = caps.get('version');

        var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter');

        testConfig = {
            reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
            outputPath: './ExecutionResults/reports',
            screenshotPath: './screenshots',
            testBrowser: browserName,
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            modifiedSuiteName: false,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true
        };
        browser.sleep(5000)
        new HTMLReport().from('testresults/xmloutput.xml', testConfig);
        browser.close();
    });
}
};
```

My test file is as below:

```
describe("Timesheet_Apply_Approved_Card", function () {
it ("Retest 1." , function(){
    //browser.get("http://www.google.com")
    //  browser.sleep(3000)
    console.log("test var : "+ testing.label)
    console.log("test " + testing._exitReasonFamilyReason)
       console.log("after test")
    expect("a").toEqual("b")
})


it ("Restest 2." , function(){
    console.log("after test 2")
    expect("a").toEqual("a")
})
})
```

But when I run the above test.js file. It does not run the failed test again.It gives below error:

```
test var : undefined
test undefined
inside method undefined
after test
Fafter test 2
.

Failures:
1) Timesheet_Apply_Approved_Card Retest 1.
Message:
Expected 'a' to equal 'b'.
Stack:
Error: Failed expectation
    at UserContext.<anonymous> 
(D:\GIT\altworklife\CARDS\test_spec\smoke\cards\test.js:20:21)

2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0.545 seconds

[17:43:43] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[17:43:43] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[17:43:43] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)


 Re-running tests , attempt :  1
 Re-running the following test files : 
 D:\GIT\altworklife\CARDS\test_spec\smoke\cards\test.js


[17:43:43] E/launcher - spawn 
C:\Users\amit.hada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor 
ENOENT
[17:43:43] E/launcher - Error: spawn 
C:\Users\amit.hada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor 
ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[17:43:43] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

It prints that it is trying again but than abruptly fails with error as given above.

Any idea, why it is failing without retrying?

Answer (score 0):

Look Like you are running your CMD from a windows laptop/server, which is not supported by this protractor-retry pkg

Comment: 2.0.1 should now support Windows